# Kibana - How to Install a locally developed plugin?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I have in my kibana directory a custom plugin "custom_plugin"
My impression from reading [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/install-plugin.html#_installing_plugins_to_an_arbitrary_directory) portion of the elastic docs is that the directory needs to be zipped.

So based on that, I do:

```
zip -r custom_plugin.zip custom_plugin
```

Then, adhering to the elastic doc example, I run:

```
mkdir plugins

bin/kibana-plugin install file:///custom_plugin.zip -d plugins
```

I get the following output:

> Warning: Using the -d, --plugin-dir option is deprecated, and is known to not work for all
> plugins, including X-Pack.
>
> Attempting to transfer from file:///custom_plugin.zip Error: ENOTFOUND
>
> Attempting to transfer
> from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/file:///custom_plugin.zip/file:///custom_plugin.zip-6.7.2.zip
>
> Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url
> specified."

Answer (score 0):

The command `bin/kibana-plugin install file:///custom_plugin.zip` will look for your file at the directory `/custom_plugin.zip`, so your root directory.

Try instead with an absolute path to your zip file as:

`file://<absolute-path>/custom_plugin.zip`